# Text Wrapping in SSRS

Tags: text, reporting-services, field, report, word-wrap

How do I accomplish text wrapping of table fields in SSRS Report, and proper landscaping when rendering the report to PDF format?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the CanGrow property to True will allow wrapping, and the text box will get as big as it needs to vertically to contain all the characters in its value.

To ensure the proper landscaping of PDF exports, set the PageSize of the report object accordingly (setting Width=11" x Height=8.5" will make a landscape PDF).

Answer (score 0):

To ensure line breaks are inserted correctly, use

```
=Replace(Fields!MyField.Value, vbLf, Environment.NewLine)
```

Set CanGrow = True.

Comment: I t is not making any difference , says vbLf as unrecognized identifier

Comment: What is the entire content of your textbox?

Comment: =Replace(Fields!pa_language.Value, vbLf, Environment.NewLine)

Answer (score 0):

Its a dumb method but if you don't have too many fields try to use the space to push the text to go to the next line.